# undefined method error in ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, undefined

I am using ruby with selenium and my code is as follows:

```
$num=1
def isElementPresent(xpathExpression)
  allElements=@driver.find_elements(:xpath,xpathExpression)

  if (allElements.size==0)
    return true
    end
  else
    return false
  end

  while Demo.isElementPresent(str1+$num.to_s+str2)
    text=@driver.find_element(:xpath,str1+$num.to_s+str2).text
    $num+=1
    puts "text is:#{text}"
    @driver.find_element(:xpath,str1+$num.to_s+str2).click
    puts @driver.title
    @driver.navigate.back
  end
end
```

I'm getting an undefined method error for `while Demo.isElementPresent(str1+$num.to_s+str2).`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, Your condition should be:

```
if (allElements.size>0)
return true
```

As if size is 0. That means no element is present.

Also, in this case your function definition should end before you are calling it.
Try following code:

```
$num=1
def isElementPresent(xpathExpression)
  allElements=@driver.find_elements(:xpath,xpathExpression)
  if (allElements.size>0)
    return true
  end
  else
    return false
  end
end
while isElementPresent(str1+$num.to_s+str2) do
    text=@driver.find_element(:xpath,str1+$num.to_s+str2).text
    $num+=1
    puts "text is:#{text}"
    @driver.find_element(:xpath,str1+$num.to_s+str2).click
    puts @driver.title
    @driver.navigate.back
end
```

Here I have made two changes: First, for the condition I explained about and Second, Ending the definition of function before your loop.

Please let me know if it works as intended.

Comment: error is of undefined method.That means isElementPresent is undefined. I need help for this

Comment: I don't think you'd need Demo for calling function.